# Could not construct instance of helper class DatabaseHelper

Tags: android, ormlite

I am doing [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-ormlite-with-sqlite-database-tutorial/) tutorial, and get following error:

`Could not construct instance of helper class class DatabaseHelper`

This where my app starts:

[image]

And here where helper get called:

[image]

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.j4nos.orm/com.j4nos.orm.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not construct instance of helper class class com.j4nos.orm.DatabaseHelper
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dbhelper , ORMLite and fragments issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948050/dbhelper-ormlite-and-fragments-issues)

Comment: @Yazan that issue does not help in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you compare to the example directly from OrmLite? [Examples](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-examples/blob/master/android/HelloAndroid/src/com/example/helloandroid/DatabaseHelper.java)

Try to create a DatabaseHelper instance by yourself, not via Manager. Then the exception output will be more detailed i guess:

```
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

Have you tried to create database and get dao in 2 steps? Maybe it should be initialized with null as in example from above.

Comment: You are right, problem was in `orm_mlight.config`, I forget update properly the file.